# readdir group folders by first letter

Tags: php, readdir, opendir

I have a list of folders but want to group them by first letter ie all A folders together, all B folder together etc:

```
$handle = opendir(".");
$projectContents = '';
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{
    if (is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$projectsListIgnore)) 
    {

$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';

    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

**Output:**

```
<ul>
 $projectContents
</ul>
```

The above snippet lists them fine from a-2-z but I don't know how to section them off into groups.

The closing and re-opening of `</ul><ul>` with each new letter section would be enough but again don't kow how to impliment into the current snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the first character of the current file name in the loop with the first character of the previous one, then print the `</ul><ul>` if they're not the same:

```
$handle = opendir(".");
$projectContents = '';
$firstLetter = '';
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{
    if (is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$projectsListIgnore)) 
    {
        if ($firstLetter != strtoupper($file{0}) && $firstLetter != '')
        {
            $projectContents .= '</ul><ul>';
        }
        $firstLetter = strtoupper($file{0}); // Store the current character for comparison
        $projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';

    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't seem to work.#, not sure if you meant to use `{0}` or `[0]` but tried with both.

Comment: Update:should be `[0]` andI got it working by removing `&& $firstLetter != ''` (kind of).

Comment: It takes into account uppercase and lowercase and seperates them, anyway to combat this?

Comment: Both should work, as described on http://php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr. I prefer the curly braces, as they make absolutely clear that the variable is not an array. `&& $firstLetter != ''` should not be removed, as it makes sure the `</ul><ul>` is not added on the first loop, but I made an error in placing `$firstLetter = $file{0};` in the if-statement. I'll update my answer, also for case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know you could use curly braces too.

Answer (score 0):

I would first store all the directories names in an array and than use asort() function to sort all the items alphabetically, and than do the link creation.